# How to eliminate multiple container components in ReactJS for code reusability?

Tags: reactjs, containers

I'm following Dan Abramov's [container & presentational components pattern](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) for a set of address forms. There are 3 different versions of the address form. They differ by layout and the controls on it. When the form is submitted, there is distinct business logic run in the backend API to return some validation message to the form.

```
Form A:

First Name
Last Name
Address
City
State
Zip

Form B:

First Name
Last Name
Address
Zip

Form C:

Full Name
Zip
```

Currently I use three containers to manage the three forms and some logic is repeated in the containers. I anticipate more forms like these in the future.

How do I solve this problem where the code can be reused for many forms as well as forms are easy to manage and understand?

Answer (score 0):

Since any React component is just JavaScript code, you can extract shared code into some utility functions/classes and use them in your form components.